# How to fix Time Limit Exceeded

Tags: c

Hi the given code is here

```
int a, b, c, d, e, f;
int fn( int n ) {
    if( n == 0 ) return a;
    if( n == 1 ) return b;
    if( n == 2 ) return c;
    if( n == 3 ) return d;
    if( n == 4 ) return e;
    if( n == 5 ) return f;
    return( fn(n-1) + fn(n-2) + fn(n-3) + fn(n-4) + fn(n-5) + fn(n-6) );
}
int main() {
    int n, caseno = 0, cases;
    scanf("%d", &cases);
    while( cases-- ) {
        scanf("%d %d %d %d %d %d %d", &a, &b, &c, &d, &e, &f, &n);
        printf("Case %d: %d\n", ++caseno, fn(n) % 10000007);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It has two problems. One is **integer overflow**. And another is **Time Limit Exceeded**. I fixed the integer overflow using **long int.** But problem is with time. When I submit the code, the online judge shows **Time Limit Exceeded**. Please help me to fix this problem.

Comment: Please post a link to the actual problem.  Per your code, if 'n' (as originally read) is less than 6 then the result is undefined behavior

Comment: in the posted code, as 'n' grows, the recursion depth greatly increases.  This can result in a stack overflow.  Probably not what the writer of the exercise wants.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a pretty standard dynamic programming problem, and the key is memoizing your function. Since this is a problem, I won't provide any code, but I will explain what you have to do. You should maintain an array of values, and before returning from your function you update the value in the array with the return value. At the start of the function, you check if that array has the return value already, and if it does, then you can just return that value.

[Read more about memoization here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/memoization-1d-2d-and-3d/).

Comment: I can not solve by what you said. I tried something like you given the link of geeksforgeeks. I get either wrong answer or time limit Exceeded. Can you give me the code of solution?

Comment: It's a challenge: you have to figure out how to code it yourself. You won't learn anything if you just copy-paste code from other people.

Answer (score 2):

Your approach has an exponential [time complexity](https://brilliant.org/wiki/complexity-theory/) and is far from ideal.
The good news is that there is a simple and easy fix.

What you can do is simply create an array whose size is the max possible value of *n*. I presume it is probably something like *10^5*, as is the standard for such problems.

Let us call this array `ans[]`. Set the first 6 values of `ans[]` manually and for the rest, run a loop which does something like this:

```
ans[i] = (ans[i-1] + ans[i-2] + ans[i-3] + ans[i-4] + ans[i-5] + ans[i-6]) % 1000000007
```

Now, for each case, you simply need to print `ans[n]` as your answer. (or `ans[n-1]` depending upon how you've stored the elements.

On a separate note, you may want to check the number with which you're taking the modulo. It is supposed to be *10^9 + 7*, yours is missing two 0s.